# getting a conncection reset error due to sftp.close

Tags: python, pysftp

I need to know about indentation of the following code. 
Which option is correct? Do I need to indent sftp.close to with or sftp.put

```
import pysftp
def sftpExample():
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None  
    with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        sftp.put('abc.csv','myfile.csv')
        sftp.close()
```

Sometimes I am getting following error and I wonder that it is due to sftp indentation 
Error copying data through the tunnel: read from tcp IP:port->IP:port:read: Connection reset by peer

Comment: When you use `pysftp.Connection` with `with`, it's context-aware. You don't need to explicitly call `sftp.close()`, the connection will be closed automatically at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: hi cody, thanks for the answer. even if I have a couple of if-else statements in that block of code.

Comment: yes, no matter what is done in the `with` block, when it ends the connection will be closed

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip. I need to check somewhere else in this case for the issue mentioned about.